# Polling an API for JSON until a specific key is found

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, conditional-statements

I'm working on a project that takes submissions and does work with the content. A details/results page is immediately available for the work submitted (job is queued for example), but results aren't necessarily ready.

What I'm trying to do is dynamically load (via jQuery) the result, displayed in two different ways, but only poll the server for one result set until `{ "status" : "success" }` appears in the json. Only then poll the server for the second content form.

Below is what I'm currently doing (straight forward) to pull in both data sets on page load. As JS is not my forte, I'm not sure how I'd go about doing an async call in a timed loop until the value of 'status' key is 'success', then displaying both result sets

Any help/suggestions appreciated :)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Pull in HTML Results
    $.get( "/api/v1/web/analysis/{{jobID}}?html=true", function( data ) 
    {
        console.log(data);
        $( "#results" ).html( data );
    });

    // Pull in raw JSON for this result report
    $.get( "/api/v1/analysis/{{jobID}}", function( data ) 
    {
        console.log(data);
        $("#JSONresults").html( "<pre>"+JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 8)+"</pre>" );
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, with help from [How to call a function within $(document).ready from outside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379529/how-to-call-a-function-within-document-ready-from-outside-it)

```
function getResults() 
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "/api/v1/analysis/{{jobID}}",
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(data) 
        {
            // Do nothing / Terminate this function
        },

        success: function(data) 
        {
            if (data.status == 'queued') 
            {
                // Wait 1.5 seconds and poll again
                setTimeout(function() { getResults(); }, 1500);

            } else if (data.status == 'success')
            {

                // Update our HTML formatted results
                $.get( "/api/v1/analysis/{{jobID}}?html=true", function( data ) 
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    $( "#results" ).html( data );
                });

                // Update our JSON content
                $("#JSONresults").html( "<pre>"+JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 8)+"</pre>" );

            } else {

                // Our status code wasn't right...
                alert("A status code was returned that indicates an issue (JSON results say _not_ 'success' or 'queued')")

            }
        },

        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
}
```

Calling `getResults()` from within `$(document).ready(function(){ getResults(); });` seems to work like a charm :)