# Issue in jquery When clicking on ok button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have wriiten jquery and html css as below lines of codes

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(function () {
         resetTimer();
         document.onkeypress = resetTimer;
         document.onmouseover = resetTimer;

         function logout() {
             var t1 = setTimeout(reallyLogout, 60000);
             $(".popup-form").css("display", "block");
         }
         var t;
         function resetTimer() {
             clearTimeout(t);
             t = setTimeout(logout, 60000); // Logout in 10 minutes
         }
         function reallyLogout() {
             debugger
             $(".popup-form").css("display", "none");
             location.href = '../login/login.aspx';
         }
         function cancel() {
             clearTimeout(t1);
             resetTimer();
             $(".popup-form").css("display", "none");
         }
     });

 </script>

<style type="text/css">
    .popup-form {
     display:inline-block;
     padding:40px;
     background-color:white;
     border:1px solid black;
     position:fixed;
     left:40%;
     top:35%;
     display:none;
     z-index:99999999999999999;
   }
</style>

 <body>
<div class="popup-form">
    <div class="popup-inner-form">
    <h4>Confirm</h4>
        You will be logged out after 60 seconds
        <input id="okbtn" value="Ok" type="submit" onclick="return reallyLogout();" />
        <input id="cancelbtn" value="Cancel" type="submit" onclick="return cancel();" />
     </div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

I have created customized form ...
which is displayed when user will be idle for 60 seconds. Actually our main purpose is that after 60 seconds when the popup is displayed. If user will not press any any button (ok/cancel), it should be redirected to login page. 
Now the issue is that when popup is displayed and ok button is clicked, it doesnot redirect it to login page... Please help me in sorting out the issue in the code!!!

Comment: why do you have `onclick="return reallyLogout();"` and `onclick="return cancel();"` you should not remove the `return` and have only the functions?

Comment: if you remove return it will works. why because initially when document is loaded it will call resetTimer() from there it reaches setTimeout(logout, 60000). After the given time i will go to logout. In Logout again you are setTimeout(), from there it points to  reallyLogout(). To avoid these looping just use $("#Custom-ID").click(function(){ required code to be execute on click ; } );

Comment: You could not access function that is created inside document ready from outside. if you want to call the function from outside then that function should defined globally is one option. check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379529/how-to-call-a-function-within-document-ready-from-outside-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since you are using instantly executed function, you shall pass `jQuery` as parameter in order for it to be active at the function scope.

`(function ($) {` --> `})(jQuery);`

You shall attach the events onclick from within the instant function scope in order to access functions as `reallyLogout` since you do not have access to the functions outside the instant function call scope because it is only executed once within this scope..

`t1` shall be declared in the global scope of the function so that you can reset it from anywhere within any nested function call `var t1;`

Here is a working example.. I have made the time 4 seconds

```js
   (function ($) {
         resetTimer();
         var t1; // set this in global scope
         document.onkeypress = resetTimer;
         document.onmouseover = resetTimer;

         function logout() {
             t1 = setTimeout(reallyLogout, 4000);
             $(".popup-form").css("display", "block");
         }
         var t;
         function resetTimer() {
             clearTimeout(t);
             t = setTimeout(logout, 4000); // Logout in 10 minutes
         }
         function reallyLogout() {
            // debugger
           console.log($(".popup-form"));
             $(".popup-form").css("display", "none");
             location.href = '../login/login.aspx';
         }
         function cancel() {
             clearTimeout(t1);
             resetTimer();
             $(".popup-form").css("display", "none");
         }
     
         $("#okbtn").click(function(){reallyLogout();});
         $("#cancelbtn").click(function(){cancel();});
     })(jQuery);
```

```css
 .popup-form {
     display:inline-block;
     padding:10px;
     background-color:white;
     border:1px solid black;
     position:fixed;
     left:10%;
     top:35%;
     display:none;
     z-index:99999999999999999;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="popup-form">
    <div class="popup-inner-form">
    <h4>Confirm</h4>
        You will be logged out after 60 seconds
        <input id="okbtn" value="Ok" type="submit" />
        <input id="cancelbtn" value="Cancel" type="submit"  />
     </div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the function which is defined inside the document ready from out of the block. create the function which is required to acccess from out as a global. see the below code snippets. i modified the **reallyLogout** and **cancel** functions as it required to access from outside.
 
 JS:

```
   $(function () {   
     resetTimer();
     document.onkeypress = resetTimer;
     document.onmouseover = resetTimer;
     var t1;
     function logout() {
         t1 = setTimeout(reallyLogout, 60000);
         $(".popup-form").css("display", "block");
     }
     var t;
     function resetTimer() {
         clearTimeout(t);
         t = setTimeout(logout, 60000); // Logout in 10 minutes
     }

    //declared the reallyLogout as a global function
    reallyLogout= function () {

         debugger
         $(".popup-form").css("display", "none");
         location.href = '../login/login.aspx';
     };
     cancel= function () {
         clearTimeout(t1);
         resetTimer();
         $(".popup-form").css("display", "none");
     }


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

When your script is running, dom elements are not loaded.
Change your script position to just before .

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<style type="text/css">
    .popup-form {
     display:inline-block;
     padding:40px;
     background-color:white;
     border:1px solid black;
     position:fixed;
     left:40%;
     top:35%;
     display:none;
     z-index:99999999999999999;
   }
</style>

 <body>
<div class="popup-form">
    <div class="popup-inner-form">
    <h4>Confirm</h4>
        You will be logged out after 60 seconds
        <input id="okbtn" value="Ok" type="submit" onclick="return reallyLogout();" />
        <input id="cancelbtn" value="Cancel" type="submit" onclick="return cancel();" />
     </div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

    // your script

 </script>

 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove return in onclick="return reallyLogout();" && onclick="return cancel();"   and also cut the reallyLogout() && cancel() implementation and paste outside the $(function() { } );

If you are using $("#okbtn").click(function(){ }); then you can use it inside the $(function() { } ); and also in that case remove onclick function in HTML.

If you follow your structure with minute changes then declare the function as global in $(function(){ } ); i.e reallyLogout = function() { // operation to performed // };

Answer (score 0):

You should add brackets to following methods:

```
t = setTimeout(logout(), 60000); // Logout in 10 minutes

var t1 = setTimeout(reallyLogout(), 60000);
```

Then, it will work. Also, I have tested.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
<input type="button">
```

instead of

```
<input type="submit">
```