# Calling a JS function to invert background-color inside a jQuery .each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

There is a question in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379529/how-to-call-a-function-within-document-ready-from-outside-it) post about calling a JS function inside a jQuery document ready function; however, it does not answer my question.

I am trying to write a function that loops over the divs in an html doc, giving the div backgrounds a random color. This portion is working. In the next step, I want to invert the divs background color using the invertColor function; however, I cannot figure out how to incorporate this function into the jQuery code.

The working code should first assign each div a random color and then invert that color using the invertColor function.

I tried calling the invertColor function both inside and outside of the .each function.

Here is the current JS code:

```
function invertColor(hexTripletColor) {
    var color = hexTripletColor;
    color = color.substring(1); // remove #
    color = parseInt(color, 16); // convert to integer
    color = 0xFFFFFF ^ color; // invert three bytes
    color = color.toString(16); // convert to hex
    color = ("000000" + color).slice(-6); // pad with leading zeros
    color = "#" + color; // prepend #return color;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").each(function() {
        var color = ["#b27485", "#74b2a1", "#cedbd9", "#abece4", "#ecabb3", "#1cdb4f", "#7e8dab", ];
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);
        $(this).css("background-color", color[rand]);
        $(this).css(invertColor(color));
        $(function() {
            invertedColor(color);
        });
    });
});
```

The HTML code and output can be viewed in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/minditorrey/hg9obznn/):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

invertColor does not return anything so you are setting `css(undefined);` and I am not sure where `hexTripletColor` is defined. And you are passing the array and not the color from the array to your method. `$(this).css(invertColor(color));`

So you are looking for something like this, I set the `color` to the inverted value that you calculate, not sure what exactly you were trying to set.

```
function invertColor(hexTripletColor) {
  var color = hexTripletColor;
  color = color.substring(1); // remove #
  color = parseInt(color, 16); // convert to integer
  color = 0xFFFFFF ^ color; // invert three bytes
  color = color.toString(16); // convert to hex
  color = ("000000" + color).slice(-6); // pad with leading zeros
  color = "#" + color; // prepend #return color;
  return {
    color: color
  };
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("div").each(function() {
    var color = ["#b27485", "#74b2a1", "#cedbd9", "#abece4", "#ecabb3", "#1cdb4f", "#7e8dab", ];
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * color.length);
    $(this).css("background-color", color[rand]);
    $(this).css(invertColor(color[rand]));
  });

});
```

Comment: Right-sorry, I've edited: hexTripletColor is the argument passed into the function.'

Comment: Thanks, this got me there. Only change to your suggested code is I need to return "background-color": color to invert background and not text. Thanks so much!

Comment: I see what you're saying, but this is my task. To first select random colors for the divs, then invert those colors by three bytes--I will also be inverting the text. Again, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`invertColor()` doesn’t return anything, so just add a return statement at the end like so:

```
function invertColor(hexTripletColor) {
    var color = hexTripletColor;
    color = color.substring(1); // remove #
    color = parseInt(color, 16); // convert to integer
    color = 0xFFFFFF ^ color; // invert three bytes
    color = color.toString(16); // convert to hex
    color = ("000000" + color).slice(-6); // pad with leading zeros
    color = "#" + color; // prepend #return color;

    return color;
}
```

Then change `$(this).css(invertColor(color));` to `$(this).css("background-color", invertColor(color));`