# Invoke javascript function in parent page from child page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I need to call a function in the main page from the child page. Below i have 2 pages. 1. main.aspx and child page is 2.active.aspx. In active.aspx  i have a button called "exit' . when i click on the exit button , i need to close the modal popup and then i need to call function "main" which is a javascript function in the main page. Problem is i am not able to invoke the function from the child page.

***Main.aspx***

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function main() {
            //do main work
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="button" class="ic-grid-encode center-btn" title="Interactive"
               data-toggle="modal" data-target="#divInterActiveContent" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="divInterActiveContent" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" align-self="" center;"="">
            <iframe id="interId" src="active.aspx"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Active.aspx***

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        self.btnExit = function () {
            parent.$('#divInterActiveContent').modal('hide');
            //after closing the popup i need to call the javascript function defined in the main page
            //i.e i need call function main which is there in the main window.
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmInterActiveEncode">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            </div>
            <hr>
            <br>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <input type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="event: { click: btnSubmit }">
                <input type="button" value="Exit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="event: { click: btnExit }">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario, you are actually closing the modal first i.e you are closing the iframe also so you are not able to get parent object in child page after closing the modal.

You should do like

active.aspx

```
self.btnExit = function () {
    parent.main();
}
```

main.aspx

```
function main(){
    $('#divInterActiveContent').modal('hide');        
    // Do your stuff
}
```

This way you can call the parent function and instead of hiding the modal in child hide it in parent function and your next stuff you want to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379529/how-to-call-a-function-within-document-ready-from-outside-it