# can we call a function outside the document.ready in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have tried doing various things but no luck. My idea is to call a function in between the php code like this  sample();  if this gets success. **Can any one help me.**

```
<p id="test"></p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    jquery_test = function() {
      $('#test').text('jquery test');
    }
    jquery_test(); // this function works
  });

  try {
    jquery_test(); // this function doesn't
  } catch(e){
    console.log(e.message); // throws "jquery_test is not defined"
  }
</script>
```

Comment: No you cannot do that, as you've defined the `jquery_test()` function within the scope of the document.ready handler.

Comment: That's because `jquery_test()` is defined inside a closure. It will not be available at the global/window scope and hence the error.

Comment: I have tried defining the function without the document.ready handler, it worked.  But that is not working if I try the same code in php. saying that function is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Define the function on the window object to make it global.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   window.jquery_test = function(){  
      $('#test').text('jquery test');  
   }  
});
```

See that : [How to call a function within $(document).ready from outside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379529/how-to-call-a-function-within-document-ready-from-outside-it)

Comment: Just be aware that it's not a good idea to pollute the `window` with functions. Declare your own namespace to do that.

Comment: @Aneeshnelavelly I dont understand why you want use php. Can you explain me ?

Comment: @Aneeshnelavelly in a comment you said : "But that is not working if I try the same code in php". What code are you talking about ?

Comment: My idea is to create popup after the registration is a success. In here I wrote a Jquery for popup and calling the function after the success in between the php code. That is not working as I'm expecting. @NicolasLamblin

Comment: @Aneeshnelavelly ok. So, can you edit your question and put your php and ajax code ?